# Use mbedTLS as SSL library in QT

Tags: qt, openssl, mbedtls, polarssl

By default QT looks for OpenSSL header during compilation to enable support for encryption/SSL in code. Due to several reasons, I want to use mbedTLS in my code instead and would like QT to use that as encryption library as well. Has anyone been able to do that?